# Acceder a los objetos en python

Tags: python, lista, poo, dataframe, objeto

Tengo la siguiente clase en Python:

```
class Equipo:

def __init__(self,codigo,concepto,cantidad):
    self.codigo = codigo
    self.concepto = concepto
    self.cantidad = cantidad
def __str__(self):
    return 'Codigo: {} | Concepto: {} | Cantidad: {}'.format(self.codigo,self.concepto,self.cantidad)
```

De un DataFrame obtengo mis objetos de la siguiente manera:

```
nombres = ['Juan', 'Laura', 'Pepe']
edades = [42, 40, 37]
cantidades = [1,2,3]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Nombre'] = nombres
df['Edad'] = edades
df['Cantidad'] = cantidades

lista1 = []
for i in df.index:
    e = Equipo #Clase
    e = Equipo(df['Nombre'][i],df['Edad'][i],df['Cantidad'][i])
    k.append(e)
```

Soy nuevo en python y no logro acceder a cada atributo, es decir a codigo,concepto y cantidad. Espero alguien pueda ayudar.

Comment: En primer lugar indenta bien tu código

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es de ideación prueba con este código:
import pandas as pd

```
class Equipo:
    def __init__(self,codigo,concepto,cantidad):
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.concepto = concepto
        self.cantidad = cantidad

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Codigo: {} | Concepto: {} | Cantidad: {}'.format(self.codigo,self.concepto,self.cantidad)


nombres = ['Juan', 'Laura', 'Pepe']
edades = [42, 40, 37]
cantidades = [1,2,3]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Nombre'] = nombres
df['Edad'] = edades
df['Cantidad'] = cantidades

lista1 = []
for i in df.index:
    e = Equipo #Clase
    e = Equipo(df['Nombre'][i],df['Edad'][i],df['Cantidad'][i])
    lista1.append(e)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera agregar una explicación de como ayudaría esté código a resolver el problema planteado. Revisar [answer], saludos